# Get multiple data element class and put in DOM elmenent

Tags: html, jquery

I want when I click on an element - another element gets the class name of the attribute that I clicked:

```js
var countryElements = document.getElementById('items').childNodes;
  var countryCount = countryElements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < countryCount; i++) {
    countryElements[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log('My Data Name: ' + this.getAttribute('data-name'));
    }
  }
  
  $('#items .check').click(function () {
    var linkHref = $(this).data('name');
    $('#provinceInfo').html(linkHref);
    $('#provinceInfo').addClass(linkHref);
});
```

```css
#provinceInfo{
background-color:#f4f4f4;
padding:30px;
margin-bottom:10px
font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="provinceInfo"></div>
<div id="items">
  <div class="check" data-name="london">United Kingdom</div>
  <div class="check" data-name="berlin">Germany</div>
  <div class="check" data-name="paris">France</div>
</div>
```

How to make it show only the current class? And not all that clicks?
Scenario: I click on Germany - the berlin class is set, I click on France - the paris class is set, and the berlin is deleted.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#provinceInfo').addClass(linkHref);
```

to:

```
$('#provinceInfo').removeClass().addClass(linkHref);
```

[`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/#removeClass) without any arguments will remove all classes from the matched elements.

```js
var countryElements = document.getElementById('items').childNodes;
  var countryCount = countryElements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < countryCount; i++) {
    countryElements[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log('My Data Name: ' + this.getAttribute('data-name'));
    }
  }
  
  $('#items .check').click(function () {
    var linkHref = $(this).data('name');
    $('#provinceInfo').html(linkHref);
    $('#provinceInfo').removeClass().addClass(linkHref);
});
```

```css
#provinceInfo{
background-color:#f4f4f4;
padding:30px;
margin-bottom:10px
font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="provinceInfo"></div>
<div id="items">
  <div class="check" data-name="london">United Kingdom</div>
  <div class="check" data-name="berlin">Germany</div>
  <div class="check" data-name="paris">France</div>
</div>
```

Comment: works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use attr instead of addclass and add your default class to it so you don't miss it.

```
$('#items .check').click(function () {
    var linkHref = $(this).data('name')+' check';
    $('#provinceInfo').html(linkHref);
    $('#provinceInfo').attr('class', linkHref);
});
```